# Using resource bundle with IDEA IDE

Tags: internationalization, intellij-idea, resourcebundle

I'm using IDEA IDE to create i18n..
I created English version of my property file and then created a Russian one.
But when I run my web application I saw  `Ïðîñìîòð Íîâîñòè` instead of my text in Russian..
Tell me please what was wrong in IDEA IDE or whether there's a bug in resource bundle plugin.

**UPDATE**

When I write I18n in eclipse and fill in all necessary fields into Russian language in Eclipse resource bundle plugin instead of Russian text I saw something like this `u0443u0434u0430u043Bu0438u0442u044C` but when I start my app it displays all well..
And when I start project in IDEA IDE with such properties everything works fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to recreate your issue using a different language (Chinese) ... I just tried this in my IntelliJ IDEA instance (I am running IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3).

I have a ResourceBundle and I dropped in Simplified Chinese characters into my Resource Bundle as follows:

**messages.properties**

```
user.label=名称
```

When I ran my Grails app through IDEA, I got characters `??` instead of the Chinese Characters `名称`

This is a bug with IntelliJ Resource Bundle Editor.  Here is a link to the Issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90460

I know it does not give you a fix, but at least it explains to you why it is happening and why you do not see the issue with Eclipse.

Comment: IDEA settings - Files Encoding - Default properties encoding = UTF-8 and transparent native2asci usage.